# Upgrading Windows service using MSI Installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-services, windows-installer

I have a Windows service in my MSI and I have created custom actions on Install and uninstall to install and uninstall my service respectively, this works fine. On an upgrade, the service throws an error of 1001. How do I upgrade my service as well using VS 10 Installer?

Comment: What do you mean by upgrading the service ? you want to uninstall existing servive and install the new service using MSI ?

Comment: Basically 1001 is caused by your custom action. did you debug into it ? what are you doing in your custom action ?

Comment: You dont need custom action to install/uninstall a windows service. MSI will take care of it.

Comment: I have done that already. I know why 1001 error comes. In the custom action, Install-> I install service and on Unintall-> I uninstall service

Comment: The Install/uninstall does not work on upgrade when it comes to service

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37996/discussion-between-accessdenied-and-aster-veigas)

Answer (score 0):

If you get tired of reinventing the wheel and fighting the bugs associated with that,  check out the [video on my blog](http://blog.iswix.com/2013/01/iswix-20130134-released.html).

It shows how to create a service and package it up as an install, check it into TFS, build it and test it on a VM in less then 10 minutes.  This installer is fully setup for Major Upgrades and will upgrade no problem if you build another release and test that also.